# Unable to set cookie with domain parameter using Universal-Cookie in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies

My react app is on localhost, APIs is on AWS lambda I want to set cookie for the API to pass user authentication token on each API call. I am using universal-cookie plugin it is working fine without domain parameter it is taking localhost by default, but when I am passing aws url in domain parameter cookie not being saved.

Here is the code I am using to set domain

```
cookies.set('cookieAuth', res.data.auth_token, { path: '/', expires: expOn, domain: '.amazonaws.com'});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not set a different domain in cookie. You can only set the domain or sub-domain where the application is running.

For an instance, if the application is running on test.com then you can set cookie for test.com or any other sub-domain of it, but you can not set cookie for xyz.com.

In this case as you have application and back-end/APIs running on two different server if you want send cookie in all subsequent API requests you have to set cookie from server side.

you can refer to [HttpOnly Cookie MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#Secure_and_HttpOnly_cookies) for understanding server side cookie / httpOnly cookie